# FileInfo to HttpPostedFileBase in mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase, system.io.fileinfo

I have a web application that has a functionality that consists in put a list of images in a folder (on the same server that the web application) and then process that images to upload them to the web application format.

For that action i have a list of `FileInfo` objects and i need to convert those `FileInfo` objects into `HttpPostedFileBase` because the `Upload` method uses this kind of object to work.

What's the best way to make this conversion?

Comment: So you want to call the Upload method directly (maybe from a Unit Test)?

Comment: It is not a unit test but yes

Comment: Just to confirm, you are not calling Upload over HTTP, right? I should have asked that right away.

Comment: Exactly.. from the action controller method i'm calling first a method to get the `FileInfo` list with the images and then on the same action i need to call the method `Upload`

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` is used in conjunction with uploading a file on the users computer to the server, yet your referring to files already on the server, so it a hard to understand what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to derive from `HttpPostedFileBase` and implements its members, mainly the `Stream` member. Return a `FileStream`. Make sure to dispose of that stream eventually. Leaking file handles on a web server can be deadly.

I would recommend an entirely different approach instead. Don't pass in an `HttpPostedFileBase`. Pass in a `Stream` or maybe a custom class. That, of course, requires you to extract the upload logic into a helper method. Don't call the web method `Upload`, call the helper. That way you don't need to create fake ASP.NET objects.